# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when i run java file from terminal

Tags: java

I am a java newbie. I have been using Eclipse to test a simple java class (named NewHelloWorld) and it runs fine in the console. When I try to do the same thing from a terminal, it compiles properly (creates a HelloWorld.class without giving any error) , but then `java NewHelloWorld` shows the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: NewHelloWorld (wrong name: org/kodeplay/kodejava/NewHelloWorld)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    Could not find the main class: NewHelloWorld. Program will exit.
```

I also tried `java -classpath . NewHelloWorld` but that doesnt work as well giving the same error.

These are the values of the environment variables:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk"
CLASSPATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/lib:."
```

Is anything else required or am I missing anything here? 
Thanks

PS: using Ubuntu 10.04 desktop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> wrong name: org/kodeplay/kodejava/NewHelloWorld

`cd` up to the package root, so that you're in the folder containing `org` folder and then do

```
java -cp . org.kodeplay.kodejava.NewHelloWorld
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message gives you a clue:

```
(wrong name: org/kodeplay/kodejava/NewHelloWorld)
```

It looks like your class is called `org.kodeplay.kodejava.NewHelloWorld`. The Java command line needs to know the fully qualified class name:

```
java -cp . org.kodeplay.kodejava.NewHelloWorld
```

should do the trick.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15775/do-you-delete-your-own-answer-when-its-a-duplicate

Comment: @BalusC: There is a difference between an *answer* and an *explanation*. The bit about "Java command line needs to know the fully qualified class name" is an explanation. I don't consider this to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the package root directory (the parent directory of `org`) and run:

`java -cp .:$CLASSPATH org.kodeplay.kodejava.NewHelloWorld`

Also I wouldn't put `.` to my `CLASSPATH` permanently (in `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` or `/etc/profile`) it may lead to undesired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`cd` up to the root package. Most of the cases it will be src folder in the Project if created from eclipse IDE.

`java -cp . org.kodeplay.kodejava.NewHelloWorld` should work

`java org.kodeplay.kodejava.NewHelloWorld` should also work. I tried both the things and it works fine in both the case

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem running a *HelloWorld* program I had written with a text editor on Mac OS X. It ran fine on a remote Linux box, but running it from home directory I got the dreaded `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Found that I could fix it either by running as:

```
java -cp . HelloWorld
```

or, without the classpath qualifier, after adding the current directory to my bash CLASSPATH for the current session:

```
export CLASSPATH=.
```

Answer (score 0):

FOR MAC USERS : 
java -classpath /Users/apple/IdeaProjects/Folder_name/out/production/folder_Name com.Package_name.class_name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).