# can not run java program on linux terminal

Tags: java, linux

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DiServer <wrong name: ds/DiServer>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626551/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-diserver-wrong-name)
>   [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when i run java file from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470386/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-when-i-run-java-file-from-terminal)

I have a program with multiple classes and compile them on the terminal with `javac *.java` and then try to run  the main file by simple doing `java filename` but it spits out the following error. I don't know what it wants. Help will be appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lab6 (wrong name: lab6/lab6)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

Comment: Please use the search before asking new questions. Many things have already been answered on SO and you may get your answer instantly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message means that you tried to execute your class using `java lab6`, but it's actually called `lab6.lab6` (i.e. it's in a package called `lab6` and its simple name is `lab6`).

To execute it, you point your classpath to the directory *containing the directory `lab6`* and execute `java lab6.lab6`.

The easiest way is to go into that directory (whatever it is called) and execute `java -cp . lab6.lab6`.

Comment: Hint: While typing the command in the terminal, try using `Tab`. Bash will autocomplete the way its needed: `java lab6.lab6`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get what was the error now.